# Difficulty Publishing In Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to test publish to my local filesystem using Visual Studio 2012, but there are no files created in the directory that I am trying to publish to.  This morning I tried to create another build configuration in Visual Studio for the solution.  Thinking that it might have caused the problem, I undid all of my pending changes to the Solution file.  I also deleted the new build configuration that I created for the assembly.  Now, the build configuration for the asp.net mvc assembly and the solution are both set to release, and the publish directory is set to a directory on my local pc.  The last two lines in the Output window after publishing the mvc solution are:

```
4>Deleting existing files...
4>Publishing folder /...
```

The folder that I am trying to publish to, however, is C:\Andrew\TestPublish.  The output also contains the following lines:

```
========== Build: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

It seems to be working, yet there are no files in the directory that I am publishing to.  Any help will be appreciated, I'm not really sure where to look.

Thank you,

Andrew

**Edit**

I have noticed that all of the files from the publishing action are appearing in the /obj/Release/Package/PackageTmp subfolder, which is located in the root folder of the asp.net assembly.  I am not sure why they are appearing in this subfolder, though...

**2nd Edit**

JesperTreetop posted the same problem in an asp.net forum, but the suggested solution, which is to make sure that the platform for the solution matches that of the mvc assembly, does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Publish Web` wizard under the `Connection` tab did you specify the location for `Target location` (just a sanity check)?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I specified: "C:\Andrew\TestPublish".  Above it, I chose for the publish method:  "File System."